# I used an object in my main file (?) despite having transferred ownership before?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I used move semantics a la

```
        class MyC {
    
    public:
Eigen::MatrixXd f_bar_mat;
    
    MyC::MyC(Eigen::MatrixXd f_bar_mat):f_bar_mat(std::move(f_bar_mat))
    }
```

In the `main` I have:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd f_bar_mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10000,200);
MyC MyInst(f_bar_mat);
MyC MyNewInst(MyInst.f_bar_mat); //transfer again
std::cout << "Access some element of the original matrix: " << f_bar_mat(3,2) << std::endl;
```

I realised only later that I erroneously called `f_bar_mat` in the body of my `main` after having transferred ownership.

However, the code still works; I don't get an error message.

Can someone help me understand the behaviour? My guess is that `std::move` then simply resorts to a deep copy. Alternatively, should I be getting a segmentation fault error or will it reference something other than `f_bar_mat` and create undefined behaviour?

Comment: `MyC::MyC(Eigen::MatrixXd f_bar_mat)` makes a copy first, then moves said copy

Comment: Please show a [mre]. It is difficult to follow a description in words. Also `std::move` does not imply that the object on which it was called cannot be used afterwards anymore. The semantics depend on what the type of the variable does with a moved object. If you are using a library, then please tag it as well.

Comment: Aside from the point by @NathanOliver (which is correct) note that moving an object puts that object into a "valid but unspecified state" so depending what operations you do with that moved object it may be defined and safe (albeit risky) to continue to use the object.

Comment: If you have an `int` object with a value of 42, and `std::move` it, you might be surprised to learn that your `int` object's value is still 42.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my point though was that I put it under ownership of the other object. So, did I succeed in avoiding a deep copy/do the efficient thing?

Comment: My point is that "ownership" can mean anything. My `int`, whose value is 42, is a field in some object. I wave a magic wand, "abracadabra!", and `std::move` this `int` field in order to "transfer its ownership" to another object. The `int` field in the original object is still 42. A given class may not implement any special move semantics it all. A "move" then gives identical results as a normal copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not moving `main`'s `f_bar_mat` anywhere. Nowhere did you call `std::move(f_bar_mat)` in `main`.

You are moving only the parameter of the constructor which is also called `f_bar_mat` but is not the same object as the one in `main` (since it was not declared as a reference).

Since you are passing `f_bar_mat` from `main` as a lvalue to the constructor, the parameter object of the constructor will be copy-constructed from `main`'s `f_bar_mat`. Only then you will move-construct the class member (also called `f_bar_mat`) from the parameter object.

Similarly at `// transfer again` you are not calling `std::move` on `MyInst.f_bar_mat`, so you are copy-constructing the constructor's parameter object again.

Comment: thank you so much! You answered my question. Would you be ok to tell me also where to call std::move in main to properly transfer the object to avoid a copy?

Comment: @KeynesCoeFen You use `std::move` directly on the variable of which you want to release ownership of state, e.g. `MyC MyInst(std::move(f_bar_mat));`, but then of course `f_bar_mat(3,2)` in the output line afterwards will be wrong.

Comment: and do I need to keep `std::move` in the initialiser list of the class?

Comment: @KeynesCoeFen If you don't want a copy to be made there, yes.

Comment: My IDE now informs me: "(clang tidy) passing an lvalue to a const reference argument, no move will actually happen." @user17732522 isn't that a bit odd?

Comment: @KeynesCoeFen There is no `const` reference in the code you are showing. If that warning comes from the code you are showing, then it means that `Eigen::MatrixXd` doesn't have any move constructor and can _only_ be copied (in which case `std::move` doesn't have any effect at all).

Comment: @KeynesCoeFen However, that should not be the case for any non-ancient version of Eigen.

Comment: Sorry I should have written "passing an lvalue AS a const reference argument." I am using Eigen 3.3 (one behind the 3.4). @user17732522

Comment: @KeynesCoeFen Doesn't change anything about what I said. There is no `const` at all in the code you are showing. A `const` object or reference cannot be moved-from.